# Spring Boot - REST method returning interface

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

## **Background**

I've a simple REST API in Spring Boot (**1.4.0.RELEASE**) which should not be connected to a datasource, and as such, needs to take in an object and use it to return another object (*interface type*) in the same method. This (kind of) unusual behaviour led me to using `RequestMethod.POST` to both be able to have **@RequestBody** and **@ResponseBody**:

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeInterface> someMethod(@RequestBody SomeClass obj) {
        SomeInterface toReturn = createSomeInterface(...);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(toReturn, HttpStatus.OK);
    } 
}
```

I also have a `Test` method:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SomeControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        SomeClass toPost = createPostObj();
        ResponseEntity<SomeInterface> respons = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/path", toPost, SomeInterface.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, respons.getStatusCode());
        assertNotEquals(null, respons.getBody());
    }
}
```

However, this throws:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Could not read document: 
Can not construct instance of SomeInterface: 
abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

## **Question**

Assuming both `SomeInterface` and `SomeClass` are belongings to other *API's* and can't be changed, is this possible to accomplish?

**Note**

I've tried to wrap the `SomeInterface` into a class without success:

```
public class Wrapper {
    SomeInterface obj;
    // getter and setter ...
}
```

Comment: `SomeInterface toReturn = createSomeInterface(...);` Do you have an implementation of SomeInterface? because you can not instantiate an java interface.

Comment: @IssamELATIF There exists an implementation `SomeInterfaceImpl` which is part of the external API yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is correct, the problem lies in your test.

The controller method returns a *SomeInterface* instance object, which is implemented by some unknown class in the external API you are using. It's probably a POJO or maybe contains Jackson annotations, and it is automatically converted to JSON/XML without problems.

But in the test you are using *RestTemplate* to call your controller and bind the result to a new object. *RestTemplate* needs a class, not an interface, to be able to create the new instance and populate it with the data received from your controller in JSON/XML format.

If you don't have access or know the class that implements that interface to use it in your test, you can change it to check for text contained into the response as explained in the ["Spring Boot documentation"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) or use a [JSON assertion library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-json-tests) if you need something more advanced.

Comment: `SomeInterface` do have an implementation `SomeInterfaceImpl` which by first eyesight looks kinda like a POJO object (only getters and setters). However, it is a long trace of inheritance from both classes and interfaces and I'm not sure how to verify if the object really can be converted to JSON/XML format (no Jackson annotations). Could you show a specific example for this test of how I could _"change it to check for text ..."_?

Answer (score 0):

> Can not construct instance of SomeInterface:  abstract types either
>   need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
>   contain additional type information

Jackson complains about passing `SomeInterface.class` as parameter to `restTemplate.postForEntity` method, Jackson can not instantiate an interface pass an implementation instead.

Your test should look like

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
    SomeClass toPost = createPostObj();
    ResponseEntity<SomeInterface> respons = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/path", toPost, SomeInterfaceImpl.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, respons.getStatusCode());
    assertNotEquals(null, respons.getBody());
}
```

Comment: Had to change to `ResponseEntity<SomeInterfaceImpl> respons = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/path", toPost, SomeInterfaceImpl.class);` or else I got a compilation error. Still doesn't work though, new stacktrace: `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class SomeInterfaceImpl] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]`.

Comment: Do you have `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` in your classpath ?

Comment: Yes. I have in my pom.xml included `spring-starter-web` which includes `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile`.

Comment: Please just try adding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1 (without any scope) in pom file.